# Mysql - Help me alter this query to apply AND logic instead of OR in searching?

Tags: mysql

First execute these tables and data dumps :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tags` (
`id_tag` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`tag` varchar(255) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_tag`),
UNIQUE KEY `tag` (`tag`),
KEY `id_tag` (`id_tag`),
KEY `tag_2` (`tag`),
KEY `tag_3` (`tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;


INSERT INTO `Tags` (`id_tag`, `tag`) VALUES
(1, 'key1'),
(2, 'key2');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tutors_Tag_Relations` (
`id_tag` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`id_tutor` int(10) default NULL,
KEY `Tutors_Tag_Relations` (`id_tag`),
KEY `id_tutor` (`id_tutor`),
KEY `id_tag` (`id_tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Tutors_Tag_Relations` (`id_tag`, `id_tutor`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1);
```

The following query finds all the tutors from Tutors_Tag_Relations table which have reference to at least one of the terms "key1" or "key2".

```
SELECT td . *
FROM Tutors_Tag_Relations AS td
INNER JOIN Tags AS t ON t.id_tag = td.id_tag
WHERE t.tag LIKE "%key1%"
OR t.tag LIKE "%key2%"

Group by td.id_tutor
LIMIT 10
```

Please help me modify this query so that it returns all the tutors from Tutors_Tag_Relations table which have reference to both the terms "key1" and "key2" (AND logic instead of OR logic). Please suggest an optimized query considering huge number of data records (the query should NOT individually fetch two sets of tutors matching each keyword and then find the intersection).

**Update**

Taking the question to the next level. Please run the following fresh queries :-

===================================================================================

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `learning_packs_tag_relations` (
  `id_tag` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_tutor` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_lp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `Learning_Packs_Tag_Relations_FKIndex1` (`id_tag`),
  KEY `id_lp` (`id_lp`),
  KEY `id_tag` (`id_tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `learning_packs` (
  `id_lp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_status` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `id_author` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_lp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tutors_tag_relations` (
  `id_tag` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_tutor` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,

KEY `Tutors_Tag_Relations` (`id_tag`),
  KEY `id_tutor` (`id_tutor`),
  KEY `id_tag` (`id_tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `surname` varchar(155) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=52 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tutor_details` (
  `id_tutor` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_tutor`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=60 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `id_tag` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_tag`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tag` (`tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

ALTER TABLE `learning_packs_tag_relations`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Learning_Packs_Tag_Relations_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tag`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id_tag`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `learning_packs`

ADD CONSTRAINT `Learning_Packs_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_author`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `tutors_tag_relations`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Tutors_Tag_Relations_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tag`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id_tag`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

INSERT INTO `test`.`users` (
`id_user` ,
`name` ,
`surname`
)
VALUES (
NULL , 'Vivian', 'Richards'
), (
NULL , 'Sachin', 'Tendulkar'
);

INSERT INTO `test`.`users` (
`id_user` ,
`name` ,
`surname`
)
VALUES (
NULL , 'Don', 'Bradman'
);

INSERT INTO `test`.`tutor_details` (
`id_tutor` ,
`id_user`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '52'
), (
NULL , '53'
);

INSERT INTO `test`.`tutor_details` (
`id_tutor` ,
`id_user`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '54'
);

INSERT INTO `test`.`tags` (
`id_tag` ,
`tag`
)
VALUES (
1 , 'Vivian'
), (
2 , 'Richards'
);

INSERT INTO `test`.`tags` (`id_tag`, `tag`) VALUES (3, 'Sachin'), (4, 'Tendulkar');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tags` (`id_tag`, `tag`) VALUES (5, 'Don'), (6, 'Bradman');

INSERT INTO `test`.`learning_packs` (`id_lp`, `id_status`, `id_author`, `name`) VALUES ('1', '1', '52', 'Cricket 1'), ('2', '2', '52', 'Cricket 2');

INSERT INTO `test`.`tags` (`id_tag`, `tag`) VALUES ('7', 'Cricket'), ('8', '1');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tags` (`id_tag`, `tag`) VALUES ('9', '2');

INSERT INTO `test`.`learning_packs_tag_relations` (`id_tag`, `id_tutor`, `id_lp`) VALUES ('7', '52', '1'), ('8', '52', '1');
INSERT INTO `test`.`learning_packs_tag_relations` (`id_tag`, `id_tutor`, `id_lp`) VALUES ('7', '52', '2'), ('9', '52', '2');

===================================================================================

About the new system - 
- The system now has 4 more tables - tutors, Users (linked to tutor_details), learning_packs, learning_packs_tag_relations
- Tutors create packs - tag relations for tutors stored in tutors_tag_relations and those for packs stored in learning_packs_tag_relations.

Now I want to search learning_packs, with the same AND logic. Help me modify the following query so that searching pack name or tutor's name, surname results all active packs (either directly those packs or packs created by those tutors).

==================================================================================

select lp.*

from Learning_Packs AS lp

LEFT JOIN Learning_Packs_Tag_Relations AS lptagrels ON lp.id_lp = lptagrels.id_lp

LEFT JOIN Tutors_Tag_Relations as ttagrels ON lp.id_author = ttagrels.id_tutor 
LEFT JOIN Tutor_Details AS td ON ttagrels.id_tutor  = td.id_tutor 
LEFT JOIN Users as u on td.id_user = u.id_user

JOIN Tags as t on (t.id_tag = lptagrels.id_tag) or (t.id_tag = ttagrels.id_tag)

where lp.id_status = 1 AND ( t.tag LIKE "%Vivian%" OR t.tag LIKE "%Richards%" )

## group by lp.id_lp HAVING count(lp.id_lp) > 1 limit 0,20

As you can see, searching "Cricket 1" returns that pack but searching Vivian Richards does not return the same pack.

Please help

Comment: Are you sure you need to use LIKE here? Perhaps you could just check for exact matches? This would work for your example data.

Comment: Hey Mark, did you remove your reply? I am actually new to stackoverflow.

I was wrong in my earlier reply, the like is needed to return partial matches. I can apply full text search to optimize later. But now can anyone help me apply the AND logic?

Comment: @ck if it is homework can you give me answer SIR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple if using Group and Having.  This should get what you are looking for.

SELECT id_tutor
FROM Tutors_Tag_Relations AS td
INNER JOIN Tags AS t ON t.id_tag = td.id_tag
WHERE t.tag LIKE "%key1%"
or t.tag LIKE "%key2%"
group by id_tutor
having count(id_tutor)>1

Comment: Hi Gary that looks simple indeed now, I also figured out such a solution. But now I want a more complex solution. Please see the update section in my question

Comment: @sandeepan If Gary's answer resolved your question you should mark it as answered and start a new question. In this new question you should make it specific not just dump a load of code in for people to plough through.

Comment: thanks Martin for the tips. Marked answered. I am new to stackoverflow actually